# Does selenium chrome webdriver version 2.3 support chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing some automation using `nunit` + `C#`. I cannot open chrome using the web drive:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Selenium\chromedriver.exe");
```

I think this issue is due to the chrome version.

Comment: Care to share what error messages you get? What happens?

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list.                                           *** This is the error message i got****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that exception because you are specifying the **full path** to the ChromeDriver.

You **must** specify the **folder** in which the ChromeDriver lives. The `ChromeDriver` class will then handle "finding" it for you:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Selenium\");
```

This has nothing to do with Chrome/Selenium/ChromeDriver versioning.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to dig out an answer in the **[Change Log](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/dotnet/CHANGELOG)** for the .NET Selenium WebDriver API.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Version 29.0.1547.65 with Selenium Webdriver 2.33.0